# What is the correct reactive pattern in Java Spring WebFlux to return a (large) file from the REST controller?

Tags: java, web-services, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-restcontroller

#### Situation:

- I have a non-reactive legacy library which expects an [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html) and writes its output into it, the method signature is something like `void produceData(OutputStream stream)`
- I want to expose the output from the method via a web service as a PDF file
- The file can be sometimes very large
- I am using the reactive framework [Spring WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html)

#### Motivation:

- I want my code to stay "as reactive as possible"
- I do not want to allocate a byte array for all the data at once, I want to maximally exploit the fact that the legacy method writes the output to `OutputStream`

#### Question:

- What is the correct reactive pattern in WebFlux to return a large file in general?
- What is the correct reactive pattern in WebFlux to return a large file when the source of the data is a non-reactive method writing to a given `OutputStream`?
- I should also be able to let the client understand that the output from the web service is a PDF file with a proper name.

#### What I am considering:

- `Mono<ByteArrayResource> getData()` - I don't want to use it because I would have to allocate the byte array for the whole content.
- In the *non-reactive* world, I would just inject the `ServletResponse` object into the controller method and passed its output stream [`ServletResponse.getOutputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream--) to my legacy method, but I don't know how to do this in the *reactive* world and if it is even recommended at all.
- `Mono<DataBuffer> getData()` - In the controller code, I can easily obtain a new [`DataBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream--) from a [`DefaultDataBufferFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DefaultDataBufferFactory.html) and use its [`asOutputStream()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBuffer.html#asOutputStream--) method, but then I don't know how to handle properly so the `DataBuffer` is released after the data are consumed by the client.

**What is the correct reactive pattern** to handle situations like this?

Answer (score 0):

Its completely ok to call a no reactive method . Its only important to keep the reactive flow reactive instead of blocking it

for example

```
someRepository.findById( id )
               .map( entity -> entity.setValue( value ) )
               .filter( entity -> entity.someCondition > other condition )
               .map( entity -> someNonReactiveLibrary.function(entity.getAttribute())) //non-reactive method
                .collect( Collectors.toList());
```

If you see the this entire block executes in one thread and it is going to be sequential. In this particular flow, you can including non-reactive method and it is completely normal.